# pass checked datagridview rows from child form to main form datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 forms

- ApodeikseisTimologion
- EggrafesTimologionEsodon

`ApodeikseisTimologion` is the main form and `EggrafesTimologionEsodon` is the childform and 1 datagridview (`dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon` and `dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon`) in each form.

`DataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon` belongs to main form and `dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon` belongs to child form.
Now, I want to pass the checked values from the child form to parent form without losing the values that i have already put in other textboxes in parent form.
Here is my code:

Form ApodeikseisTimologion.
I use this to open the child form

```
private void LinkLblEisagogiEggrafon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    EggrafesTimologionEsodon eggrTimolEsodon = new EggrafesTimologionEsodon(cmbBoxEponimiaPelatiApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Text);
    eggrTimolEsodon.ShowDialog();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Form EggrafesTimologionEsodon

```
private void EggrafesTimologionEsodon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {

        con = new SqlConnection();
        con = DBAccess.Conn;
        con.Open();

        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProionParastatikou.* from ProionParastatikou inner join Parastatiko on ProionParastatikou.ParastatikoID = Parastatiko.ParastatikoID" +
                                      " where ProionParastatikou.Ypoloipo > 0.00  and Parastatiko.Eponimia = '" + txtPelatisId.Text + "'", con);
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "BsProionParastatikouEsodon");
        dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    finally {
        if (MyConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have this image :

[image]

in the child form i also have this to check the rows from the checkbox column of the datagridview and stored them to a list to transfer them to the parent form without losing the other data that i have already.

```
private void BtnProsthikiEggrafon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ApodeixeisTimologion apo = new ApodeixeisTimologion(null);
    List<Int64> lst2send = new List<Int64>();
    Int64 toSend;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow eggrafes in dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.Rows) {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(eggrafes.Cells["CheckBoxColumn"].Value)) {
            int RowIndexCheck = eggrafes.HeaderCell.RowIndex;             
                 Int64.TryParse(dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.Rows[RowIndexCheck].Cells["proionParastatikouIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(),out toSend);
                lst2send.Add(toSend);
            }
        }

        apo.AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(null, null, lst2send);
        //apo.Refresh();
        this.Close();
    }
```

When the child form close, I have that in parent Form:

```
public void AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(object sender,EventArgs e,IList<Int64> lst) {
    String csvLst = string.Empty;
    int count = 0;

    foreach ( Int64 lstItems in lst) {
        if (count == 0) {
            csvLst = lstItems.ToString();
            count += 1;
        }
        else {
            csvLst = csvLst + "," + lstItems.ToString();
        }
    }

     _con = new SqlConnection();
     _con = DBAccess.Conn;
     _con.Open();

     adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProionParastatikou.* from ProionParastatikou where" +
            " ProionParastatikou.Ypoloipo > 0.00  and ProionParastatikou.ProionParastatikouID"+
            " in( " + csvLst + ")", _con);

     ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
     adap.Fill(ds, "bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon");//
     dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.DataSource = ds.Tables["bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon"];
     //dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Refresh();
     _con.Close();

 }
```

i make a breakpoint in

```
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds, "bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon");//
dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.DataSource = ds.Tables["bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon"];
```

And i see that the ds fills with the correct values but rows are not coming in the dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon which is the grid in parent form.

In all the forms i am using datasets and bindingSources in datagrids, and the datagrids are bounded except of the checkbox column.
Can somebody helps.
If someone needs more help i will give it.

Comment: Thanks for the editing...Can you help?

Comment: Sorry i don't that i understand what the problem is.... maybe can you try to explain better what is the issue here ?

Comment: The problem is that i can not transfer them in the main form

Comment: You mean that your data in the grids in the Child forms does not getting transferred into the main form right ?

Comment: you are right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form ApodeikseisTimologion. I use this to open the child form

```
private void LinkLblEisagogiEggrafon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbBoxEponimiaPelatiApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Πρέπει να επιλέξετε Πελάτη", "Προειδοποίηση");
            }
            else
            {

                EggrafesTimologionEsodon eggrTimolEsodon = new EggrafesTimologionEsodon(cmbBoxEponimiaPelatiApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Text);//p

                eggrTimolEsodon.ShowDialog();

                listToFill = eggrTimolEsodon.lst2send;

                AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(null,null,listToFill);

                //AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(null);
                //this.Refresh();

            }


        }
```

Form EggrafesTimologionEsodon

```
private void EggrafesTimologionEsodon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //CmbBoxPelatis.SelectedIndex = -1;

            //EggrafesTimologionEsodon values = new EggrafesTimologionEsodon();
            try
            {

                con = new SqlConnection();
            con = DBAccess.Conn;
            con.Open();

            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProionParastatikou.* from ProionParastatikou inner join Parastatiko on ProionParastatikou.ParastatikoID = Parastatiko.ParastatikoID" +
                                      " where ProionParastatikou.Ypoloipo > 0.00  and Parastatiko.Eponimia = '" + txtPelatisId.Text + "'", con);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "BsProionParastatikouEsodon");
            dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            finally
            {
                if (MyConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    MyConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

From that I am having the image which is on top.

```
public List<Int64> lst2send;

        private void BtnProsthikiEggrafon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lst2send = new List<Int64>();
            Int64 toSend;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow eggrafes in dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(eggrafes.Cells["CheckBoxColumn"].Value))
                {
                    int RowIndexCheck = eggrafes.HeaderCell.RowIndex;             
                    Int64.TryParse(dataGridViewEggrafesProionParastikouEsodon.Rows[RowIndexCheck].Cells["proionParastatikouIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(),out toSend);
                    lst2send.Add(toSend);
                }

            }
            this.Close();

        }
```

When the child form close, I have that in parent Form:

```
public List<Int64> listToFill;

        public void AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(object sender, EventArgs e, IList<Int64> lst)//object sender,EventArgs e,
        {
            String csvLst = string.Empty;
            int count = 0;
            foreach ( Int64 lstItems in lst)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    csvLst = lstItems.ToString();
                    count += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    csvLst = csvLst + "," + lstItems.ToString();
                }

            }
            _con = new SqlConnection();
            _con = DBAccess.Conn;
            _con.Open();


            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProionParastatikou.* from ProionParastatikou where" +
                                                     " ProionParastatikou.Ypoloipo > 0.00  and ProionParastatikou.ProionParastatikouID"+
                                                     " in( " + csvLst + ")", _con);

            DataSetApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon ds = new DataSetApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon();

            adap.Fill(ds.ApodeixeisProionParastatiko);//

            bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.DataSource = ds.ApodeixeisProionParastatiko;// Tables[0];
            dataGridViewProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.DataSource = bsProionApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon;

            _con.Close();

        }


private void LinkLblEisagogiEggrafon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbBoxEponimiaPelatiApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Πρέπει να επιλέξετε Πελάτη", "Προειδοποίηση");
            }
            else
            {

                EggrafesTimologionEsodon eggrTimolEsodon = new EggrafesTimologionEsodon(cmbBoxEponimiaPelatiApodeixeisTimologiouEsodon.Text);//p

                eggrTimolEsodon.ShowDialog();

                listToFill = eggrTimolEsodon.lst2send;

                AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(null,null,listToFill);

                //AfterProsthikiProionParastatikou(null);
                //this.Refresh();

            }


        }
```

And I am having the results that I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO2Cm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal, but working sample.
Have a public property on your Form2, and access it from Form1. My snippet is passing a string, but yours will be dealing with a different data type. Same concept, different data type.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassParamsFromForm2ToForm1_45997869
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2("blah blah blah");
            f2.ShowDialog();
            label1.Text = f2.returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassParamsFromForm2ToForm1_45997869
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string returnValue;
        private string submittedString { get; set; }
        public Form2(string incomingString)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            submittedString = incomingString;
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            returnValue = "I'd rather show you my value instead of yours(" + submittedString + ")...";
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Working with Grid types

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PassParamsFromForm2ToForm1_45997869
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<gridentry> gridList = new BindingList<gridentry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        DataGridView gridViewForTheReturnedRows;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initializeGrid();
            addDataToGridSource("name1");
            addDataToGridSource("name2");
            addDataToGridSource("name3");
            addDataToGridSource("name4");
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        }

        private void addDataToGridSource(string incomingString)
        {
            gridList.Add(new gridentry { col1 = incomingString, col2 = incomingString + "in col2", col3 = incomingString + "in col3" });
        }

        private void initializeGrid()
        {
            dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv.DataSource = gridList;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(dgv);
            f2.ShowDialog();

            if (f2.returnRows != null && f2.returnRows.Count > 0)
            {
                gridViewForTheReturnedRows = new DataGridView();
                gridViewForTheReturnedRows.ColumnCount = f2.returnRows[0].Cells.Count;
                gridViewForTheReturnedRows.Rows.InsertRange(0, f2.returnRows.ToArray());

                gridViewForTheReturnedRows.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, dgv.Location.Y + dgv.Height + 5);
                this.Controls.Add(gridViewForTheReturnedRows);
            }
        }
    }

    public class gridentry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PassParamsFromForm2ToForm1_45997869
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public DataGridView returnGrid = new DataGridView();
        public List<DataGridViewRow> returnRows { get; set; }
        private DataGridView submittedGrid { get; set; }


        public Form2(DataGridView incomingGrid)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            submittedGrid = incomingGrid;
            submittedGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            Controls.Add(submittedGrid);
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        }


        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            returnGrid = submittedGrid;//if you want to return the grid

            //returning rows
            /*
             * You'll need your own mechanism to differentiate between 
             */
            bool rowIsModified = false;
            returnRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in submittedGrid.Rows)
            {
                if (item.Index % 2 != 0)
                {
                    rowIsModified = true;
                }
                if (rowIsModified)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow r = (DataGridViewRow)item.Clone();
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        r.Cells[i].Value = item.Cells[i].Value;
                    }
                    returnRows.Add(r);
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how it can helps...I want to transfer the ckecked rows from the child form back to the main form.If you want you can see the image that i have.

Comment: The snippet shows how to transfer data from form2 to form1. If you are wondering how to differentiate between modified and non modified rows so that you can transfer only the modified ones, perhaps you should reformulate your question.

Comment: I think that you are transfering only a text, right?

Comment: how can i tranfer a datagridview?

Comment: yeah, but as stated... The type you pass around is solely up to you. I'm passing a `string` because the property I use to return the value is declared as such `public string returnValue;`. If in `Form2` instead I had declared that `public DataGridView returnValue;` then I could have I could have done `returnValue = dataGrid2OnForm2`.

Comment: @VagelisDaldavanis, updated code with a minimal DGV sample.